# Table borders show up randomly with border: 0

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, border

Only happens in Google Chrome browser and only on Microsoft Surface.

The code is as simple as:

https://jsfiddle.net/8fudnx9q/5/

```
<table id='settings-menu' class='menu'>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Settings</b></td>
    <td><a href='?go=settings&category=users'>Users</a></td>
    <td><a href='?go=settings&category=resources'>Resources</a></td>
    <td><a href='?go=settings&category=notifications'>Notifications</a></td>
    <td><a href='?go=settings&category=tickets'>Tickets</a></td>
    <td><a href='?go=settings&category=clients'>Clients</a></td>
    <td><a href='?go=settings&category=billing'>Billing</a></td>
    <td><a href='?go=settings&category=inventory'>Inventory</a></td>
    <td><a href='?go=settings&category=interface'>Interface</a></td>
    <td><a href='?go=settings&category=profile'>Profile</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.menu td {
  background-color: #737373;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 1em;
}
.menu td a {
  color: white;
}
```

Chrome version Version 49.0.2623.87 m, Windows 10, Surface Pro 3.
Resolution: 2160x1440

Original Screenshot:

[image]

With `<tr>` filled and `<!-- comments`:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Does this fix it? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/8fudnx9q/6/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith: Nope.

Comment: One more try https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/8fudnx9q/7/

Comment: See the screen shot, better but still visible... Sounds like rending issue...

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It is not a border issue. I am having trouble since I am not using windows 10 and cannot duplicate, I have one more idea.

Comment: OOPS, here it is https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/8fudnx9q/8/

Comment: You fixed it, but seems like a dirty workaround....... Is it rendering bug?